# Trying to start appium server from the command line but keep getting this error

Tags: python, appium

```
C:\Users\13024\PycharmProjects\UltraShop_Clean
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
[debug] [W3C]     at ADB.signWithDef
```

java is installed and working  it does have two \bins that do not exist

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 
Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 
'C:\Android\Studio\jre\bin\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
```

my system envs:

[image: win10 env]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the /bin from my java env Var and restarting computer worked.

Comment: my env java_home does not contain 'bin'